# : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') Type Error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm encountering an issue with my React application where I'm receiving a TypeError related to reading properties of undefined. Here are the details of the problem:

**Problem Description:**
When navigating to a specific page in my React application, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
```

This error occurs in a component that is supposed to access parameters from the URL using React Router's match.params. However, it seems that the match object is undefined, leading to the error.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Verified that React Router is correctly set up and that the routes are configured to pass parameters.
2. Reviewed the affected component's code to ensure that it's correctly structured to handle route parameters and access the match.params object.

**Code Snippet (Affected Component):**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-material-ui-carousel';
import "./ProductDetails.css";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { getProductDetails } from '../../actions/productAction';

const ProductDetails = ({ match }) => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const {product} = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  

  useEffect(() => {
  
      dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
    
  }, [dispatch, match.params.id]);
  
  
  return (
    <Fragment>
        <div className='ProductDetails'>
            <div>
                <Carousel>
                    {product.images && product.images.map((item , i)=>(
                    <img className='CarouselImage' 
                        key ={item.url}
                        src={item.url} 
                        alt={`${i} Slide`} />
                    ))}
                </Carousel>
            </div>
        </div>

    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

**Additional Information:**
Redux actions and reducers seem to be working correctly as per the Redux DevTools.
No error messages are displayed in the console or Redux DevTools.
[ReduxDev Tool snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYUMF.png)

**Request for Assistance:**
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this TypeError and ensure that the match.params object is correctly accessed without encountering undefined errors. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "Verified that React Router is correctly set up and that the routes are configured to pass parameters" - Are you sure about this? What version of React-Router are you trying to use? Can you also [edit] to include a complete [mcve] so we can see the routes and the component navigating to the product details page?